# Unable to register a Tenant through Laravel controller

Tags: laravel, multi-tenant

```
$ php artisan tinker
>>> $tenant1 = App\Models\Tenant::create(['id' => 'foo']);
>>> $tenant1->domains()->create(['domain' => 'foo.localhost']);
```

The above commands are working fine on CLI

but when I write them in the controller and link them with a form then, domains are inserted, tenants are inserted and a new database is successfully created with the name of the tenant

```
$subdomain = $request->subdomain;
$subdomain_link = $subdomain.".locahost";

$tenant = \App\Models\Tenant::create(['id' => $subdomain]);
$tenant->domains()->create(['domain' => $subdomain_link]);
```

the above code is my controller code and the issue is when I hit the route it returns

`Tenant could not be identified on domain app.localhost`

Comment: What middleware are you using? `InitializeTenancyBySubdomain` or `InitializeTenancyByDomain`?

Comment: @dbf I am using InitializeTenancyByDomain  in my tenant.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$subdomain_link = $subdomain.".locahost";
```

The issue was the type of `localhost`